# How to create lattice plot title with new line, italics and variable names in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I've been trying to add a title (via main) to a map created with spplot that consists of two lines of text, but with the second line italicised. The text in each line is drawn from a variable name. I've variously tried using bquote and expression, but with no luck.

A basic example of my starting point is below, although in my actaul usage the text for a and b are drawn iteratively from a vector as part of a loop. Any suggestions as to how to keep the two lines split as per the example, but with the second line of text italicised would be much appreciated. I hope the example is clear. Thanks in advance.

```
require(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)<-~x+y

a<-"line 1"
b<-"line 2"
title<-paste(a,'\n',b,sep="")

spplot(meuse,c("ffreq"),col.regions="black",main=title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spplot(meuse, c("ffreq"), col.regions="black",
               main= expression( atop(line~1, italic(line~2) ) )  )
```

If you really wanted to isolate the a="line 1" and b="line 2" variables and "pass them in",  you could use this form:

```
spplot(meuse, c("ffreq"), col.regions="black",
             main= as.expression( bquote( atop(.(a), italic(.(b) ) ) ) ) )
```

I will note that the value returned by bquote() is not actually an expression but rather a "language"-object. Deepayan Sarkar, lattice's author, is of the opinion that these do not deserve being considered as expressions in the lattice framework. Using `bquote` without the as.expression wrapper is generally acceptable in base graphics and in ggplot2, but will fail in lattice calls. I initially (unsuccessfully) tried:

```
 spplot(meuse, c("ffreq"), col.regions="black",
             main=  bquote( atop(.(a), italic(.(b) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The second of these worked for me - I'd tried both the first and last previously. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the first solution does not seem to work when the text to be included is a variable name.

Comment: That's correct. Text that look like names of variables inside `expression()` do not get evaluated. The `as.expression` arguments do get evaluated and then returned with mode 'expression'